# Play Framework 2 referrals to a different routes...java scala

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.1

This loop prints out three Continents.

```
@(cont: List[Continent])



@for(contin<-cont){
<li>

    @contin.name

</li>
```

}

This loop displays the country of the continent.

```
@(country: List[Country])



@for(co<-country){
    <li>
    @co.code
    </li>
}
```

This my routes:

```
GET        /                    controllers.Application.continent()
GET        /eu                  controllers.Application.countryEU()
GET        /au                  controllers.Application.countryAU()
GET        /us                  controllers.Application.countryUS()
```

example:

```
<a herf="/eu"><a>
<a herf="/au"><a>
<a herf="/us"><a>
```

I want each of these continents led me into the country belonging to the continent, 
in a separate view.

Comment: It sounds like you want to render a hyperlink in each of your list items. Please include the entry from your ``routes`` file for this link so that we can see the URI pattern and the associated method call.